# Android appcompact Toolbar title from manifest

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

Im using Appcompat Toolbar in Drawer Layout inside FragmentActivity. Inside each fragmentActivity need to change the title based on the activity. Is there any way to set title from Manifest instead of setting in each activity onCreate toolbar.setTitle("ABC").

NOTE: Im not using getSupportActionBar(toolbar)

FirstActivity extends BaseActivity

Themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<color name="primary">#457C50</color>
<color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
```

Android Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sample.md.FirstActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="First Activity" >            
</activity>
```

Toolbar initialize in Base Activity

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = 
    new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            try {
                toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }

};

mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a label attribute like this:

```
<activity
        android:label="My Screen"
        ... >
```

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake with it. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set a `label` attribute.

Comment: Does it work if you do `setTitle()`? If not, then your app theme might be hiding it.

Comment: Yes, its working if set title through setTitle in each fragmentAcitivity onCreate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Hamad: My answer is actually a solution, and my comment was further diagnosing it since the solution should work. I don't see the need to fragment the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTitle()` in your Activity/Fragment.